# Handling checkboxes in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a html form to login, which contains amongst other inputs a checkbox for the "Remember me" function. For the other textboxes, I've been letting MVC match them up automatically (probably a word for that). So for textboxes I'd do "string [textboxname]" as a parameter, and that all works fine. I thought for a checkbox I could just do "bool [checkboxname]" but that does not work. Here is my form in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("login", "accounts"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("email_username", null, new { @class = "textbox login email", placeholder = "Email or Username" });
    @Html.TextBox("password", null, new { @class = "textbox login password", placeholder = "Password", type = "password" }); 
    @Html.CheckBox("remember_me", new { @class = "checkbox remember-me" });
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button login" />
}
```

And my controller action that handles the form submission:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string email_username, string password, bool remember_me)
{
    //Do things    
}
```

What would be the best way to go about handling this?

**UPDATED CODE:**

I've updated the action on the controller to take a model as a parameter instead of individual parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Model.User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<string> Errors = new List<string>();
        if (user.Email.Length == 0)
        {
            Errors.Add("You need to enter an email");
        }
        if (user.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            Errors.Add("You need to enter a password");
        }
        if (Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            //Return errors to view
            TempData["LoginErrors"] = Errors.ToArray();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("new", "recipes");
    }

    return View();
}
```

And changed the form in the view to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("login", "accounts"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "textbox login email", placeholder = "Email or Username" });
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "textbox login password", placeholder = "Password", type = "password" }); 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> x.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox remember-me" });
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button login" />
}
```

Here is my user model with relevant fields:

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; protected set; }
    public string Password { get; protected set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; protected set; }

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string email, string password)
    {
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        RememberMe = false;             
    }
}
```

Comment: For Checkboxes and Boolean values to work with MVC you really need a ViewModel rather than accepting form values as action parameters.

Comment: This is because the `CheckBoxFor` helper will write out a hidden `<input type="hidden" />` in addition to the `<input type="checkbox" />` which helps with processing HTML checkboxes.

Comment: I've changed it now so that the Login action is using a single model instance instead of the parameters, and changed my Html.TextBox lines to Html.TextBoxFor( x=> x.Email) etc, but when I post the form it seems not to populate the action's model instance. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show your model and the POST method - we can't guess what you have done wrong

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated it, take a look.

Comment: @Frayt, You need to roll back your last edit, then add the new code after it (the question and comments now makes no sense). Then you also need to add the model. Possible cause is your model has fields, not properties (no get/set)

Comment: @StephenMuecke As you wish ^^

Comment: You problem is that you have private and protected setters on your properties so the `DefaultModelBinder` cant bind then - just use `public string Email { get; set; }` Also for the password, use `@Html.PasswordFor()` and remove `type = "password"` and recommend you also add validation attributes such as `[Required]`, `[EmailAddress]` etc. with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` then none of that code for checking the length etc is required.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Is removing protected the only way of doing this? I'm coming over from ASP web forms and I was taught to use protected set, then use a constructor to populate the instance, and create methods like "ChangeEmail" within the class if you need to change the field later. Also thanks for the suggestion about validation messages and the `[Required]` but I'm going to be doing manual validation/verification in the controller. I will use `PasswordFor` however.

Comment: The properties must have public setters. Why would you choose such a fragile way of validating. MVC does this all out of the box, including client side validation for you. And there is no point calling `if (ModelState.IsValid)` since the model will always be valid your way. And what about validating the `Email` is actually a valid email address etc. etc.?

Comment: I want to do it manually so I have greater control over the validation and the way error messages are represented to the user.

Comment: No you don't. Your putting some messages into `TempData` and redirecting to another page (If the user refreshed that page the messages would disappear). Then you expect the user to redirect back to the login page and try and remember what the error was on the previous page (they are now gone forever). The user has to re-enter everything all over again, even the stuff that was correct. I can't imagine a worse user experience. Learn the basics of MVC and use client side validation to display the messages you want so the user can correct them before submitting the form.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I do plan to use client validation in the form of Jquery, with server side being a backup.